# Cannot implicitly convert Type 1 to Type 1

Tags: c#, visual-studio

This is going to be my first question asked on stackoverflow so please bear with me.

here is the error i am getting
error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'Sales.Mhebe.Data.Contact' to 'Contact'.
 Now this wouldn't be so weird if i had not already done it with 3 other class.
ie) Sales.Mhebe.Data.Employee to Employee.
Any guidance would be very much appreciated.

```
protected void PopulateContactFields()
{
    string contactID = FKContactIDTextBox.Text;
    if (contactID == "")
    {
        MessageLabel.Text = "Please Select a Sales Person ID";
        ClearFields();
        DetailPanel.Visible = false;

    }
    else
    {
        ContactController contactControllers = new ContactController();
        try
        {
            int lookupContact = int.Parse(contactID);
            Contact contacts = contactControllers.LookupContact(lookupContact);
            if (contacts == null)
            {
                MessageLabel.Text = "Contact" + lookupContact + " not found";
                DetailPanel.Visible = false;
                ClearFields();
            }
            else
            {
                PKContactIDTextBox.Text = contacts.ContactID.ToString();
                NameStyleTextBox.Text = contacts.NameStyle;
                ContactTitleTextBox.Text = contacts.Title;
                FirstNameTextBox.Text = contacts.FirstName;
                MiddleNameTextBox.Text = contacts.MiddleName;
                LastNameTextBox.Text = contacts.LastName;
                SuffixTextBox.Text = contacts.Suffix;
                EmailAddressTextBox.Text = contacts.EmailAddress;
                EmailPromotionTextBox.Text = contacts.EmailPromotion.ToString();
                PhoneTextBox.Text = contacts.Phone;
                PasswordSaltTextBox.Text = contacts.PasswordSalt;
                PasswordHashTextBox.Text = contacts.PasswordHash;
                AdditionalInfoTextBox.Text = contacts.AdditionalContactInfo;
                ContactRowGuidTextBox.Text = contacts.RowGuid.ToString();
                ContactModifiedDateTextBox.Text = contacts.ModifiedDate.ToString();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageLabel.Text = "Error Populating Contact Fields with exception " + ex.Message;
            DetailPanel.Visible = false;

        }
    }

}
```

The Error is at Contact contacts = contactControllers.LookupContact(lookupContact);

If you need to say any of the other Classes regard contact please let me know.

Comment: Contact contacts = (Contact)contactControllers.LookupContact(lookupContact);

Comment: you need to Convert it like i did in last comment

Comment: also please post the definition of both classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `Contact` class in the name space that is not `Sales.Mhebe.Data.Contact`, Assigning object to Sales.Mhebe.Data.Contact will remove the error

```
Sales.Mhebe.Data.Contact  contacts = contactControllers.LookupContact(lookupContact);
```

If you want to assign `Sales.Mhebe.Data.Contact` to other Contact class then you can make object of `Contact` class using `Sales.Mhebe.Data.Contact`

```
Sales.Mhebe.Data.Contact  salescontacts = contactControllers.LookupContact(lookupContact);
Sales.Mhebe.Data.Contact  contacts = new Contact{ContactPublicProperty1 = salescontacts.Property1, ContactPublicProperty2 =  salescontacts.Property2}
```

Comment: Holy Man, thanks a lot! i will have to find this contact class.

Comment: if both classes have same field and properties, in that case what should happened same error will be thrown??

Comment: That wont compile as they seem incompatible.

Comment: due to namespace difference if both are exactly same but namespace different that won't work right??

Comment: Ask yourself why you made two different types with the same fields. Simply put, do not do that. Make exactly one.

Comment: Yes, but it is due to class incompatibility, same class name do not make them compatible. It is like we can not assign object of A class to B class if they are independent (not base-derived, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you have some sort of a name clash. Notice the error message says about `Sales.Mhebe.Data.Contact` and `Contact`. Compiler always operates on a full class names and that appears that in context `Contact` results in being interpreted as class named `Contact` (without any namespaces). Check if

```
Sales.Mhebe.Data.Contact contacts = contactControllers.LookupContact(lookupContact);
```

would work. Then either eliminate name clash, or continue to use a full class name.